# Five letter words with one vowel difference

Tags: word

Looking for 5 letter words where just the vowel is different.

Eg. Bland, blind, blend

but to cover all 5 vowels.

Answer (score 9):

There's several options for you, and which you consider valid would differ from anyone else.

So in the vein of teaching you to fish, here is your question as a [Qat search on Quinapalus](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=%7CAB%7C%3D4%3BAaB%3BAeB%3BAiB%3BAoB%3BAuB%3B&ent=Search&dict=0)

> `|AB|=4;AaB;AeB;AiB;AoB;AuB;`

The initial search, without the length check is actually one of the examples given in the [About Qat page](https://www.quinapalus.com/qat.html).

Naively I added `|AaB|=5` for each vowel, which is not permitted. So instead I have *one* check that `|AB|=4`.

This is as far as it got for the UKACD dictionary:

| A | E | I | O | U |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b·a·lls | b·e·lls | b·i·lls | b·o·lls | b·u·lls |
| b·a·nds | b·e·nds | b·i·nds | b·o·nds | b·u·nds |
| b·a·tty | b·e·tty | b·i·tty | b·o·tty | b·u·tty |
| c·a·res | c·e·res | c·i·res | c·o·res | c·u·res |
| c·a·tes | c·e·tes | c·i·tes | c·o·tes | c·u·tes |
| g·a·lly | g·e·lly | g·i·lly | g·o·lly | g·u·lly |
| h·a·cks | h·e·cks | h·i·cks | h·o·cks | h·u·cks |
| h·a·llo | h·e·llo | h·i·llo | h·o·llo | h·u·llo |
| m·a·lls | m·e·lls | m·i·lls | m·o·lls | m·u·lls |
| m·a·res | m·e·res | m·i·res | m·o·res | m·u·res |
| m·a·ses | m·e·ses | m·i·ses | m·o·ses | m·u·ses |
| m·a·ssy | m·e·ssy | m·i·ssy | m·o·ssy | m·u·ssy |
| m·a·tes | m·e·tes | m·i·tes | m·o·tes | m·u·tes |
| p·a·cks | p·e·cks | p·i·cks | p·o·cks | p·u·cks |
| p·a·nts | p·e·nts | p·i·nts | p·o·nts | p·u·nts |
| p·a·ppy | p·e·ppy | p·i·ppy | p·o·ppy | p·u·ppy |
| r·a·cks | r·e·cks | r·i·cks | r·o·cks | r·u·cks |
| cl·a·ck | cl·e·ck | cl·i·ck | cl·o·ck | cl·u·ck |
| sn·a·bs | sn·e·bs | sn·i·bs | sn·o·bs | sn·u·bs |
| tr·a·ck | tr·e·ck | tr·i·ck | tr·o·ck | tr·u·ck |
| man·a·s | man·e·s | man·i·s | man·o·s | man·u·s |
| min·a·s | min·e·s | min·i·s | min·o·s | min·u·s |

It's possible there's more solutions, but the page times out:

> Total solutions found: 22 in 14.380s

But that's all it found

Comment: That's not a timeout - it'll give you a more direct message if it times out. That's just telling you how long it took to finish.

Comment: Some other dictionaries reports timeout, however some find 30 or more solutions.

Comment: @Deusovi ahhh good to know!

Answer (score 0):

14 seconds? Pshaw! I found 20 results in 0.08 seconds from a word collection I have and a search program I wrote. Those not included in another answer and listed in Merriam-Webster are

> [bally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bally) [belly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belly) [billy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/billy) [bolly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolly) [bully](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bully)
>  [chack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chack) [check](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check) [chick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chick) [chock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chock) [chuck](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chuck)